# Style Layout Panes in CSS with JavaFX FXML without creating a variable?

Tags: java, css, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I'm working with JavaFX FXML, and I'm having a bit of trouble styling my app with CSS.

I have a `GridPane` on my root node, and I'd like to style it's background. The `GridPane` itself was never mentioned in the Java code (`@FXML`) because it didn't have to - it was never used at all in the code.

However, I'm styling the app now and all I can get from [Oracle's Official Guide of Styling Layout Panes with CSS](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/style_css.htm) is that I'll have to create a variable like so: `GridPane grid = new GridPane();` and then proceed to assign the variable a style, like so:

```
.grid {
    -fx-background-color: white;
    -fx-background-radius: 5.0;
    -fx-background-insets: 0.0 5.0 0.0 5.0;
    -fx-padding: 10;
    -fx-hgap: 10;
    -fx-vgap: 10;
}
```

And then proceed to add the style to it, like so: `grid.getStyleClass().add("grid");`.

This is an unfeasible solution for me as I have multiple `GridPane`s in multiple scenes throughout the project, and I can't have to manually create a variable for all of them.

Is there a solution similar to styling a button?

A button can be styled without requiring to create a variable for it, and it will automatically style all buttons on the scene, like so:

```
.button{
    -fx-text-fill: rgb(49, 89, 23);
    -fx-border-color: rgb(49, 89, 23);
    -fx-border-radius: 5;
    -fx-padding: 3 6 6 6;
}
```

Comment: From the [GridPane-Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html): GridPane may be styled with backgrounds and borders using CSS.  See [Region](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html) superclass for details. And CSS for Region is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region). But changing region isn't a good advice. So your solution is quite good, and maybe you need to add the classes in a loop.

Comment: GridPane has no style class by default, so you will have to manually add the style class to it

Comment: @Kachna how would one do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GridPane` doesn't have a own style class (see [CSS reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#gridpane)), but similarly to tag selectors in HTML, `Node`s can be selected by their java classes:

```css
GridPane {
    -fx-background-color: white;
    -fx-background-radius: 5.0;
    -fx-background-insets: 0.0 5.0 0.0 5.0;
    -fx-padding: 10;
    -fx-hgap: 10;
    -fx-vgap: 10;
}
```

Furthermore is is possible to add style classes from FXML since [`styleClass`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#getStyleClass--) is a [Read-Only List Property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#read_only_list_property_elements):

Short form for a single style class:

```xml
<GridPane styleClass="grid">
     ...
```

Long form for multiple style classes:

```xml
<GridPane>
     <styleClass>
          <String fx:value="grid"/>
          <String fx:value="myclass"/>
     </styleClass>
     ...
```

It is also possible to add style classes from the properties view in SceneBuilder.